# How to Access MongoDB with Spring Batch using SSL

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, ssl

Using Start.Spring.IO,   I created a Spring project for use with MongoDB. The autoconfiguring used by Spring works great for a local MongoDB.   However, I need to access a MongoDB that is on another server.  This server requires the use of SSL certs.   Looking at all the "properties" that Spring has for Mongo,  I do not see anything relating to SSL.

```
# MONGODB (MongoProperties)
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database= # Authentication database name.
spring.data.mongodb.database= # Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the FieldNamingStrategy to use.
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database= # GridFS database name.
spring.data.mongodb.host= # Mongo server host. Cannot be set with URI.
spring.data.mongodb.password= # Login password of the mongo server. Cannot be set with URI.
spring.data.mongodb.port= # Mongo server port. Cannot be set with URI.
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.type=auto # Type of Mongo repositories to enable.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # Mongo database URI. Cannot be set with host, port and credentials.
spring.data.mongodb.username= # Login user of the mongo server. Cannot be set with URI.
```

Is there a SSL property for Spring/MongoDB that I'm missing?   Does Spring not support SSL with MongoDB?

If there is no property, how would using the Spring framework with MongoDB be configured to use SSL?   (I've seen Java examples on how this may work, but they did not apply to the Spring Framework).

One possible thing I saw, was using the URI property.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://host/test?ssl=true
```

however, I could not get that to work.  If I checked the Mongo logs,  it would show something like this.

```
2018-05-11T17:50:41.196-0500 W NETWORK  [conn309195] no SSL certificate provided by peer
```

Guessing I'm missing something...just don't know what.

Comment: this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557746/parse-mongodb-ssl-no-ssl-certificate-provided-by-peer).